# How to treat partially done partially cancelled cards

Tags: agile, scrum, personal-projects, kanban

I use an online kanban-board for my projects. Even though I work mostly alone, it helps me keep track of what would otherwise be an Alexandran Library of post-it notes. While I'm sure my process is pretty far away from actual kanban/scrum, I try to keep my process similar where possible, as it helps me avoid process deviation that would change the process in the long term.

One thing I'm unsure what to do with are cards that are partially finished, with the remainder cancelled. For example, a card consists of tasks A through C, where A and B are completed and C was no longer a requirement.

Do I:

- Move the card to "done", despite one of the tasks not actually being done?
- Trash the card, and make a new one without C, and then move that to "done"?
- Something else?

What does scrum and/or kanban say about this?

Comment: If the acceptance criteria has changed, I would just update the card and move it to done.  Maybe put a comment or strike-through for the previous criteria so the reader is not shocked at the sudden disappearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend scissors.  If you insist on grouping multiple tasks on one card it's going to have multiple states.

The rest of the world solves this problem with check boxes but if your process needs the card to be in two places at once you need two cards.

Comment: +100. Cut the tasks mercilessly. The key to closing many tickets is having _small_ tickets.